# to store char* from function return value

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to implement a function which reads from Serial Port ( Linux) and retuns char*.
The function works fine but how would I store return value from function.
example of function is

```
char  *ReadToSerialPort()
{
 char *bufptr;
 char buffer[256];  // Input buffer/ /
 //char *bufptr;      // Current char in buffer //
 int  nbytes;       // Number of bytes read //

 bufptr = buffer;

 while ((nbytes = read(fd, bufptr, buffer+sizeof(buffer)-bufptr -1 )) > 0)
 {
  bufptr += nbytes;
  //  if (bufptr[-1] == '\n' || bufptr[-1] == '\r')
  /*if ( bufptr[sizeof(buffer) -1] == '*' && bufptr[0] == '$' )
  {
   break;
  }*/

 } // while ends


 if ( nbytes ) return bufptr;
 else return 0;


 *bufptr = '\0';

} // end ReadAdrPort


//In main
int main( int argc , char *argv[])
{ 
  char *letter;
  if(strcpy(letter,  ReadToSerialPort()) >0 )
  {
   printf("Response is %s\n",letter);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should indent your code using the "{}" tool in the question editor. Mark your code and click that, alternatively do it manually by indenting all of your code at least 4 spaces.

Comment: First, this is not C++, but this is C-style.  Second, I even dont see where you want to store what you read in bufptr that points on buffer. Where do you want to put the data ?

Comment: The line "*bufptr = '\0';" will never ger executed as you return before you get there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should allocate a buffer at heap with `malloc`, and return it. The users of your function will be responsible for deallocating the memory (and your documentation has to clearly state this!)

A simple change would be

```
char* buffer = (char*)malloc(256);
// beware that now `sizeof(buffer)` will be not 256 any more, but 4, so
// you have to define your constant for it.
...
if (nbytes) return buffer;
free(buffer);
return 0;

...
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    char *letter = ReadToSerialPort();
    if (letter)
    {
        printf("Response is %s\n", letter);
        free(letter);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Please note that the code `*bufptr = '\0';` should be before `return`, not after!

**EDIT**
Does your code look like this:

```
char *ReadToSerialPort()
{
    const int buffer_size = 256;
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(buffer_size);
    char *bufptr = buffer;
    int  nbytes;

    while ((nbytes = read(fd, bufptr, buffer+buffer_size-bufptr-1)) > 0)
    {
        bufptr += nbytes;
    }

    *bufptr = '\0';

    if (bufptr != buffer)
        return bufptr;
    // else cleaning up
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

I am curious where does `fd` come from?

Comment: Better to return the NULL constant rather than 0 on failure.

Comment: @Tim: I copied that part from the OP's code. But you're right.

Comment: @samprat: beware that `sizeof` behaves differently with `char buffer[256]` and `char* buffer`. I've added the comment to the answer.

Comment: But `0` and `NULL` are the same in this context.  Also, `sizeof buffer` is not necessarily 4, it is `sizeof(char *)`.

Comment: Hi Guys,  I have tried above sample code , but it throws segmentation fault error. I am pretty sure like its something to do with size of buffer. and since if sizeof(buffer) size =4  ... what should i do to replace it in while stmt part?

Comment: @samprat: a simple way is to define a named constant 256 (either as const int (if your compiler allows it) or as #define), and use it in the `malloc` line, and instead of `sizeof`.

Comment: I did tried that before but it hasnt worked. I will try now again with extra cautions and see if it works or not.THANKS A LOT VLAD for quick  responses.

Comment: hi Guys,I have tried to replace the while stmt inside char*ReadTo SerialPort() from original to something like  const int bufferSize = 1024 while ((nbytes = read(fd, bufptr,  buffer+sizeof( bufferSize)-bufptr-1 )) >= 0)  but all, iam getting is segmentation fault  of some very long error with "aborted message at the end"

Comment: `sizeof(bufferSize)` is incorrect, just use `read(fd, bufptr, buffer+bufferSize-bufptr-1)`

Comment: Hi Vlad,   the fd is integer from serial port indicating its open for read and write. I have tried your modified code and still its showing segmenation fault.

Comment: @samprat: at which line does it crash?

Comment: it complies properly, but when I try to make any event happen via serial port  it crashes. I have put some debug stmt inside ReadTo Serial port and i have a feeling that something is gng wrong there.

Comment: @samprat: but do you see at which exactly **line** does it crash?

Comment: Thanks guys for quick response and my special Thanks to Vlad  for taking keen interest in my problem. Well, Vlad, I have solved the problem , it seems like the snippet yoy have provided to me works flawlessly but there is some other problem with serial device something with bzero .. I hope , will able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Fix up your main code to look like this:

```
//In main
int main( int argc , char *argv[])
{ 
  char *letter = ReadToSerialPort();
  if(letter != NULL)
  {
   printf("Response is %s\n",letter);
  }
}
```

Make sure you use the buffer declared as `static` within `ReadToSerialPort()`.....
i.e.:

```
static char buffer[256];
```

Comment: This is the simplest and easiest way to ensure that the buffer will remain static to prevent garbage upon function going out of scope!

Comment: But this will fail in the code like `char *letter = ReadToSerialPort(); char *letter2 = ReadToSerialPort();`, the second call will overwrite the result of the first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your function a bit more. You can not simply say it "returns a `char *`". Where are the characters it points to? In a static buffer? On the heap (allocated by `new`)? It looks like you are trying to return a pointer to a local buffer (allocated on the stack), which is an error. Alternatively, return a `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the signature of **ReadToSerialPort()** to also inform the caller how many bytes you are returning. So you could do either this:

```
int ReadToSerialPort(char** data);
```

or this:

```
void ReadToSerialPort(char** data, int* num_of_bytes);
```

and you stay responsible for allocating memory space inside ReadToSerialPort().

The user would do something like (not tested):

```
int main( int argc , char *argv[])
{ 
  char* data = NULL;
  int count = 0;
  ReadToSerialPort(data, &count);
  if (data != NULL && count > 0) // Let's suppose count returns as 5
  {
    printf("data[0]:%x data[1]:%x data[2]:%x data[3]:%x data[4]:%x\n", data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4]);
  }

  // and the user is responsible for deallocating data himself
  free(data);

  return 0;
}
```